# Call Ajax Play FrameWork

Tags: playframework-2.1

I have a problem with ajax, play framework 2.1.1:

My Play Project

routes:

POST     /sample/testapi                           controllers.Application.testapi()

GET     /sample/ajax                           controllers.Application.ajax()

Application.java

```
   public static Result testapi() {
           DynamicForm dynamicForm = DynamicForm.form().bindFromRequest();
           String data= dynamicForm.get("data");
           Logger.debug(data);
           return ok("<user no='1'><id>1</id><name>Peter</name></user>");
    }
    public static Result ajax() {
           return ok(ajax.render());
    }
```

When I call action "testapi" from ajax.scala.html through ajax

My ajax code

$.ajax({
      url : "http:// localhost:3333/sample/testapi",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {data: "test"},
    dataType: "text",
    success : function(result) {
           alert(result);
    },
    error : function(request,error) {
           alert(error);
    }
});

It working fine.

And I have a html file and I call to play project through ajax.

The action had been called, but not return result and show alert "error".

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Use some inspection tool in your browser to open the POST (ajax) request in new window and check if your controller doesn't throw some exception. It's hard to say what's wrong with your call.

Comment: it's error status is 0

Comment: Just for giggles, have you tried using the routes controller for the API endpoint instead of hard-coding the route into the url variable? This may not be the issue either, but it looks like you are sending XML data back, but you set it to accept "text" types.

Comment: If AJAX is working and the controller is being called, but not sending back a result, have you checked your Application.log file?

Comment: "text" or "xml" type not working too. I think it's not problem.
I don't understand using the routes controller for the API endpoint instead of hard-coding the route into the url variable. Can you explain for me?

Comment: I add response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); to my action and it working fine. Thanks.

Comment: You should add that as the answer below then. You didn't mention anything about cross-origin requests in your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I added "response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");" to my action.

```
   public static Result testapi() {
       response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

       DynamicForm dynamicForm = DynamicForm.form().bindFromRequest();

       String data= dynamicForm.get("data");
       Logger.debug(data);
       return ok("<user no='1'><id>1</id><name>Peter</name></user>");

}
```

"response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");" allow other domain call it.